# TypeError: list object not found in python

Tags: python, typeerror

in my code in python

```
for i in array_config(1,len_config):
    print array_config[2]
```

shows

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

(array_config is an array of configuration file)
(len_configs value is 7)

how to remove that error?

Comment: What are you trying to *do*? You cannot use the list as a function, but what was your goal instead?

Comment: And why print just `array_config[2]` repeatedly?

Comment: Perhaps you mean `array_config[1:len_config]`?

Answer (score 1):

You're calling array_config like a function in the first line. It feels like you meant to write this:

```
for i in array_config:
    print i
```

Comment: I don't know...I think he is trying to slice `array_config`.  Why else would he have the 1 and `len_config`?

Comment: Just a hunch... probably len_config == len(array_config)

Comment: The original code is so broken, that you just have to guess what the author wants. This might be the right answer.